# Integer adding problems with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, integer, fibonacci

We are currently learning JavaScript in our labs and we just created a simple Fibonacci function that calculates first 100 numbers of the Fibonacci sequence.

```js
function fibo(stop) {
  let counter = 0;
  let first = 1;
  let second = 1;
  let third = 0;
  console.log(third);
  console.log(second);
  console.log(first);
  while (true) {
    third = second;
    second = first;
    first = second + third;
    counter++;
    if (counter >= stop) {
      break;
    }
    console.log(first);
  }
}

fibo(100);
```

Now when I run it there's a section that just magically adds numbers together wrong.

[image: Screenshot of console]

When I separately add those exact two numbers together in JavaScript, I get the same answer as the third line in the screenshot. However when I redo the adding on a calculator, it shows `14 472 334 024 676 221` instead of `14 472 334 024 676 220`. My first guess was that it has something to do with Integer Overflow, but then again log2(14472334024676220) = 53.684... which means  that in a 64 bit integer it is not overflowing. Why is it so? Where does it come from? I tried asking my teacher but he had no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with integers, the maximum safe integer (i.e where n + 1 !== n) is `9007199254740991` which is 2^53 - 1

Javsacript Numbers are 64 bit floating point, that doesn't mean integers

Use BigInts - to initialise a BigInt youse can use the `n` suffix to a number as below

```js
function fibo(stop) {
  let counter = 0;
  let first = 1n;
  let second = 1n;
  let third = 0n;
  console.log(third.toString());
  console.log(second.toString());
  console.log(first.toString());
  while (true) {
    third = second;
    second = first;
    first = second + third;
    counter++;
    if (counter >= stop) {
      break;
    }
    console.log(first.toString());
  }
}

fibo(100);
```

Note: the Stack Snippet console.log fails to log BigInt which is why I put the `.toString()`